# Recursion using automake behaves unexpectedly

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have an autotools setup coexisting with a traditional Makefile in a single repository. In order to avoid overwriting ./Makefile, I have set configure.ac to copy Makefile.in into Makefile.test.

There is a subdirectory that is managed by the generated Makefile.test. When I run

```
    make -f Makefile.test clean
```

the script correctly enters the test directory, runs clean, and steps out of the directory. However, upon returning to the root it attempts to call clean-am, using what appears to be a plain

```
   make clean-am
```

This invokes the wrong make file, and I get the following error.

```
    rm -f *.lo
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/somedude/work_repos/some-repo/test'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/somedude/work_repos/some-repo'
    make[2]: *** No rule to make target `clean-am'.  Stop.
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/somedude/work_repos/some-rep'
    make[1]: *** [clean-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/somedude/work_repos/some-repo'
    make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Any help on how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your static makefile to something different, and generate the makefile as you normally would with the Autotools, outputting makefile or Makefile, not Makefile.test.

This is solved by not naming your Automake-generated makefile anything other than one of the recognized filename patterns, "makefile" (all lowercase) being the first and most portable. I just tried the same thing, and all it does is `$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-recursive`, which expands to `make all-recursive` for me.

In other words, Automake cannot handle the concept of makefiles with alternate filenames, mainly because in order to generate the correct code, it would need to know about them. Since it doesn't (and possibly cannot), it is forced to assume a default makefile filename.

The ability to rename an input/output filename probably was not meant for this. It was created, if you can infer the reason from the manual's example, due to the DOS limitation of the 8.3 filename; config.h.in isn't a valid filename, so you must map the input file generating config.h to config.hin for example. Using it to rename the makefile generated from Makefile.in or whatever filename you used obviously doesn't work.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

your best bet is probably to use a filename for the Makefile, which fullfills the following criteria:

- get's picked automatically (so you don't need to specify the `-f` flag)
- overrides the default makefile
- does not clash with `Makefile` (so you can keep the other makefile around)

reading `man make` you get:

> `make` executes commands in the `makefile` to update one or more target `names`, where `name` is typically a program.  If no **-f** option is present, `make` will look for the make‐files `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order.

so the obvious choice is to use `GNUmakefile` as your autotools makefile.

as long as you don't have run `./configure` your filesystem tree will look like:

```
 Makefile
 GNUmakefile.in
 GNUmakefile.am
 configure
 [...]
```

so running `make` will call the *default* (legacy) makefile.
after your configure-run, there will also be a `GNUmakefile` in the path, and `make` will automatically pick the new shiny autotools Makefile.

i've used this successfully to maintain two parallel `make`-based build systems.

Comment: The problem with using the name `GNUmakefile` is that it will only work if the user is using gnu make.  However, simply using the name `makefile` (with a lower case `m`) should work just fine.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the problem with `makefile` (lowercase), is that it will get you into big trouble on filesystems that are not case-sensitive (the default on W32 and OSX)

Comment: Another option is `makefile,v`  (Build a makefile and use RCS `ci` to construct `makefile,v`)

Comment: btw, if someone is using `GNU autotools`chances are high that they are *also* using `GNU make`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell could you elaborate on `makefile,v`? these days most systems don't have `rcs` installed and i don't know of any `make` implementation that uses a `makefile,v`...or do you mean something else?

Comment: umlaute: I was thinking that the user would have RCS, but perhaps the comment was not adequately considered.  However, the make standard requires that make recognize SCCS files, so it should be portable to use an SCCS file instead.  (Although overall I think this is a really bad idea, and the build should simply be configured so that either tha particular directory simply does not have a Makefile.am, or the functionality of the custom makefile should be moved into Makefile.am)

Comment: The maintainer using the autotools to generate the configure script is not the user.  The user very well may not have gnu make available.

Comment: @WilliamPursell your distinction between upstream developer and user is correct; however, in practice i have *never* found a problem with the `GNUmakefile` approach (and my projects do need to compile on a number of different systems and are used by a couple of users)